# Keyboard shortcuts for selecting range using Inputbox in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using Excel 2010 and I have a problem with using keyboard shortcuts for choosing ranges in an Inputbox.

I am using a standard `Application.Inputbox` with `type:=8`. The code prompts the user to open a file (an already existing workbook) and then prompts him with this Inputbox to select a range.

I am able to select the range with the mouse. However, the keyboard shortcuts (like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT ARROW</kbd>) for selecting a range don't work completely:

They work when I select a range in the same workbook where the code is, but they don't work **on a newly opened workbook**.

Is there a way to enable keyboard selection for ranges?

Comment: I've observed this same sort of behavior when inserting a chart or changing the data linked to the series of a chart. Highly annoying.

Comment: The newly opened workbook, is that opened via VBA or some other way? Have you tried activating both the workbook and the worksheet you want the selection to be made in?

Comment: @snoopen, the workbook is opened via VBA using standard Application.GetOpenFilename command. I did activate both the workbook and worksheet from which the data was to be read. I still couldn't use keyboard shortcuts though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a similar issue as with the Ref Edit Control, see [MS KB 213776](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213776) for details about this control which you can use for VBA UserForms. (I make extensive use of this control in my VBA solutions.)

Microsoft has provided a workaround for the problem with the Ref Edit Control here: [MS KB 291110](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291110) and I can imagine this will also help you with the `Application.InputBox`-problem.

Edit: and after posting my answer I noticed that this question has been asked AGES ago... :-(

Comment: Thanks for the comment CoRrRan. Yes it was quite long ago that i posted this. Unfortunately, i do not work with project anymore. Thank you for your reference though. I'll have a look. cheers.